# Use different shell for scp

Tags: ssh, scp

I want to use a different shell when Im scping files to a remote server as compared to when Im logging in. Is there a way to do this? Note that both scp/remote login is done with the same user, so I cant assign scponly as the shell.

The reason I want to do this is because I want my bash_profile to be executed only when I remote login not when Im scping files.

Edit:

Ok so the problem really is my bashrc being executed not my bash_profile as I mentioned before. I source my bashrc from my bash_profile to keep things in one place. I image if I could specify scp to use a shell other than bash then the problem would go away.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). The real solution is [not to print from `.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18647/108618).

Answer (score 1):

Your `~/.bash_profile` isn't executed when SCP:ing. I tested this by adding

```
echo "$(date)" >> "${HOME}/test"
```

to the end of `~/.bash_profile` and looking at `tail -f ~/test`. On SSH login, a new line was written. On SCP access, a new line was not written.

Have you noticed some unwanted behavior, or did you just assume that it would be a problem?